# Datalist - how to launch function on click option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem with `datalist` with my `input` search in VueJS, why when i click with mouse or with enter on one of the option on my `datalist`, my function `getData()` which is called to `@click` and `@keypress.enter` is not launched?

here is my code:

template:

```
          <input
            list="data"
            v-model.trim="searchBy"
            @keyup.enter="getAllDatas"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Find more data..."
          />
          <br />
          <datalist id="data">
              <option v-for="r in repos.items" 
                      :key="r.id" 
                      :value="r.name"
                      @click="getData(r.id)"
                      @keypress.enter="getData(r.id)"  />
          </datalist>
```

script:

```
 methods: {
    getAllDatas() {
      fetch(`someURL`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
          res => {
            this.data = res
          }
        )
    },
    ...mapActions(["fetchData"]),
    async getData() {
       await this.fetchData();
  },
```

i totally have no idea what is wrong here, can someone tell me?

Comment: I don't see the getData() in your methods section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<datalist>` control doesn't have it's own events, you have to use the `<input>`.  Both clicks and keyboard events will trigger the input's `keydown` listener.

```html
<input
  list="data"
  v-model.trim="searchBy"
  @keydown="getData"
  @keyup.enter="getAllDatas"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Find more data..."
/>
```

This will pass the event to the handler, so unless you can work around that, you might want to use a `<select>` instead, or a custom control.

Comment: I cant do that because i need to provide an attribute to my `getData` function but in `input` i have no data to do it

Comment: In that case, you can't use a datalist.  Your choice is a `<select>` or a custom control that mimics the behavior of the datalist.

Comment: Can you show example witch `select`? I'm so weak at frontend but i need this control :( plz

Comment: Well, it's basically what you have here but without the input.  So you wouldn't get the typing ability with it.  If you need that, then you have to use a custom control.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I need with typing in my input, cause when i type some on the input, then i return data from api depending on what was entered there

Comment: Then you need a custom control.  It can't be done with datalist or select.

Comment: So I should use some type of simple table?

Comment: Not a table, you need something like this https://vue-select.org.    Vuetify also has something like this, called a [combobox](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/)

Comment: Thanks @Dan, it helps!